# JavaScript not detecting mobile device and redirecting

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to determine if the device is an android or an iphone and then redirect it accordingly. However when I test it it does not work It just loads the html file. Any ideas why this does not work? Also I really have no experience with java script. I stick mainly to mobile dev. I opened the url on an iphone and android and had no luck with either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <script>
         var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
         var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
         if (isAndroid) {
            // Do something!
            // Redirect to Android-site?
            window.location = 'http://espn.go.com/';
         }

         if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
            if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == - 1) window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com/;
         }

      </script>
      <title>Redirect</title>
      <script>
         // google analytic code is here
      </script>

         Redirecting 
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to output the result to see what the result is and that is finding what you want like alert(isAndroid); or alert(ua)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `document.location` instead of `window.location`.

`document.location = "http://google.com"`

**UPDATE**

actually, you can still use `window.location`, you just missed the trailing `"` in your url:

BAD: `window.location = "http://google.com;`
GOOD: `window.location = "http://google.com";`

Answer (score 3):

You just have syntax error:

```
window.location = "http://www.yahoo.com/;
```